# ASP.Net Core clear two-factor "remember me" preference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

On the .NET scaffolding two-factor authentication page, the user has the ability to "Remember this machine" so that they will not be prompted for two-factor at their next login. I would like to keep this preference available to the user.

However, there is a particular branch of code where I would like to reset the state of this preference, if a user has checked that box, and force a user to go through the two-factor authentication process.

.NET's `SignInManager` provides two methods of use, `IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync`, `ForgetTwoFactorClientAsync`. However, what I'm finding is that the "Remember this machine" preference is only forgotten at the next page request.

I suspect this state is tracked by the request cookies which are immutable. Is there any way for me to forget this preference with immediate effect?

```cs
if (await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user))
{
    await _signInManager.ForgetTwoFactorClientAsync();
}

if (await _signInManager.IsTwoFactorClientRememberedAsync(user))
{
    // We still reach here, even with our call to ForgetTwoFactorClientAsync above 
}
```

Comment: I think it sets a response header to remove the cookie, so it won't affect the current request's state.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I'm curious if there's any way to manipulate the state used by `SignInManager` so that a call to `PasswordSignInAsync` will always fail for users with 2FA enabled (with `SignInResult.RequiresTwoFactor`)